# How to manage UFW via PHP site

Tags: php, selinux, ufw

I'm trying to create a PHP script which allows management of certain UFW firewall rules from a web portal.  I'm using exec("sudo /sbin/ufw {command}") to apply the changes that are received, but it only works when SELinux enforcement is disabled.  I've tried audit2allow based on the audit logs, created a custom module, but still when I turn enforcement back on, it fails.

Error:

```
ERROR: initcaps
[Errno 2] iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

I'm able to execute the same command as in the script from the command line, even with enforcement enabled.

```
sudo -u apache sudo /sbin/ufw {command}
```

User: apache

Linux: RHEL 7.5

Comment: Well, most likely the process is not allowed to use the ``sudo`` command like that (without a password), did you whitelist that command?

Comment: This is my entry in sudoers:
"apache ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ufw"
I can run the sudo command stand alone even with selinux enforcement enabled. I'm guessing it has something to do with the command being executed within the httpd daemon or thread, but I'm not familiar enough with selinux

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I just ran into the same issue.  I wrote a custom php script to alter a specific firewall rule.  I used a static sudo nopasswd entry to let apache user execute one script as root that should be able to add or remove a rule.  But selinux is fouling it up.  audit.log looks like sudo isn't running, but i added echos to my bash script and i see the output in chrome.

Comment: Sorry @billy, I'm trying to rack my brain on why I was setting this up or which project it was for, but I don't remember.  If I had found a solution I likely would have posted it, so I suspect I changed approaches

Comment: I likewise pivoted to another solution.  my commands were simple enough I used SSH command-locked keys and php ssh's to the server on which it's running.  SSH 'breaks out' of selinux so that solves it kind of.  Though a flagrant misuse of SSH.  I'm not even sure if I want to consider it an answer I can be proud of, but it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't very elegant, but try ssh instead of sudo.

Have you ever noticed that you never run into SELinux problems with commands you try to run yourself as an admin on the CLI?  It's always things that begin executing via cron/systemd, or begin executing from an http connection.....

Well sshd and the shells started by it are basically excluded from selinux enforcement, and you can use that to your benefit here.

First read up on ssh keys, and on command-locked keys.

Then make a new keypair just for this command:

> ssh-keygen -f id_rsa_commandyouwant -P ''

Install that keypair in the user's authkeys file:

> echo -n
> 'command="/path/to/your/script",no-port-forwarding,no-x11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding' >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
>
> cat id_rsa_commandyouwant**.pub** >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

The string in single quotes we're echo-n'ing in above will lock down the key so it can not be used to get an interactive shell.  When that key is used with that user account, only the script will be executed.

If your script needs to receive arguments, you can use the ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND} variable in your script (with careful sanitization).  Simply provide the arguments as if they were commands when you call the ssh client, and the whole cmdline string will show up in ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}.

By all means, if your script can run non-root, do so, and replace root's homedir above.

So, instead of:

> exec("sudo /sbin/ufw {command}")

Try:

> exec("ssh -i /path/to/id_rsa_specialusecase root@localhost {command}")

And make a script which I will call /path/to/your/script that reads ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}, validates it is sane and safe (doesn't contain ; rm -rf /) and then calls:

> /sbin/ufw ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}

Happy sysadmining!

Comment: Turning off SELinux is a much safer option than leaving root private keys around your network.

Comment: @symcbean It sounds like you don't understand what "Command Locking" a keypair means.  "root private keys" implies they can execute any command as root.  The example I gave can not because they are locked to a specific command.  It is akin to allowing specific commands without password via /etc/sudoers